# How to call a method in odoo 7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I've created a method and I was using field function to call the method. But, the method never executes.
here is my code :

```
def _get_data_from_puchase_order(self, cr, ids, field, arg, context=None):
    print "SUCCESS"
    print ":::::::::::::::::"
    result = {}
    for row in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        print row
        print "::::::::::::"

_columns = {
        "data_purchase_product" : fields.function(_get_data_from_puchase_order, method=True, string='origin', type='char', strore=False)
    }
```

i was add :

```
for data in self.pool.get('purchase.order').browse(cr, uid, ids):
    print data.name
    print "++++++++++++++++++"
```

and i got error :

```
MissingError: ('MissingError', u'One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.')
```

Answer (score 0):

This help,

ids : list of id of your object,

```
def _get_data_from_puchase_order(self,cr,uid,ids,name, args, context=None) :
        print "SUCCESS"
        print ":::::::::::::::::"
        result = {}
        for row in ids:
            result[row] = "test"
        return result 

_columns = {
        'data_purchase_product': fields.function(_get_data_from_puchase_order, string='origin', method = True, type='integer'),
    }
```

Comment: hey it's work, but when i was try add ```for data in self.pool.get('purchase.order').browse(cr, uid, ids):``` the looping not executes, but the rest your code is executes ??

Comment: @Scarlettstone, edit your quetion and post the error pls

Comment: Done, you can check the question