# odoo xml cannot show the field

Tags: python, xml, odoo

i was try to show the field on the xml. But, the problem is ? the fields it's doesn't show. here is my code :

```
xml file.

<tr>
   <td class="bottom_border_only" ><span t-field="o.test_field_function"/></td>
</tr>
```

python file

```
def test_function(self,cr,uid,ids,origin, args, context=None) :
    print "success"

'test_field_function' : fields.function(test_function, method=True, string='data_po', type='char', store=True),
```

Comment: Hi @Scarlett stone, Your function does not return values, and you have already asked the same question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644444/how-to-call-a-method-in-odoo-7/46645162#46645162

Answer (score 1):

Your field will never have a value the way that you declared it.  In the function you need to set the value of the field i'm using my phone but in the new api the function should be like this.

```
    @depends('some_field') 
   def test_function(self) :
       for rec in self:
             # loop because self can have more than one record
            rec. test_field_function = "success"
```

printing a message will just print it to the stdout witch is the console check odoo code to see how to use compute fields there is plenty is an open source you finf elegant code writing by professionals

Comment: your code using odoo 8 version, and i using odoo 7 version

Comment: You can refer this answer from odoo forum:
 https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/openerp-fields-function-explanation-13118

This might be helpful in your case